# Textpad: How to serialize / concat multiple replacements

Tags: textpad

I have to use Textpad in my environment. To treat a file (on a regular basis) it is necessary to make +/- 20 replacements, some of them regex, some of them not. For most of the replacements I have defined macros (for each replacement one macro, i. e. 1:1). It is possible to "concat" macros or put replacements "in a sequence"? If it is possible: Would this sequence break, if one replacement does not find matching patters (off course, it should not break).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would "concat" them aside from recording each macro together (unless you know how to concat the files)... but as your question is about "would it work"... then I'd say yes but you would have to ensure each marco started in the right place.

I'd recommend each macro started and ended with something like Ctrl+Home to ensure a consistent starting / ending place

Comment: I naively assumed I could copy them together. But macros are somehow compiled. Another way could be to call macros in macros? Perhaps only if they have some key combination assigned. To make one big macro is perhaps error-prone.